How large giant kelp can grow?
The giant kelp (Macrocystis pyrifera,
Laminariales) is the largest extant species of (brown) algae. Yet, there are many different claims about how large this species can grow. Of course, I am aware that it is quite hard to give a definite answer, but I would like to find a trustable source. Searching via google, one finds many different claims with oddly specific numbers but without any source. Let me give some examples:

The Guinness Book of World Recors states (see here) that

The longest verified specimen attained a total length of 60 m.
However, there are unverified records of even longer specimens.

Now, although the Guinnes book includes many fascinating facts about
animals and life in general, it never gives any sources, which makes it to me (at least when it comes to records in science), to a barely reliable
source. Furthermore, 60 meters seems to be quite exaggerated.

Wikipedia states

Individual algae may grow to more than 45 metres (150 feet) long at a
rate of as much as 60 cm (2 ft) per day.

again, without source, althoug later in the text they also mention
the number of 60 meters citing a textbook on Phycology (Hoek, Mann, Jahns: Algae: An Introduction to Phycology, Cambridge University Press).

The Webpage of the Monterey Bay Aquarium says here that giant kelp can grow "up
to 100 feet (30 m); 175 feet (53 m) under ideal conditions", which
seems to be a quite specific number, but again, without any source.


Does anyone have a reliable source or study on the size of giant brown algae species?

The wikipedia article does indeed have references under the "Growth" section. 8, 25, 26. I suggest you check those out and then come back with anything you don't understand.
